# How to run FIORI app which is using reusable library in SAP WEBIDE?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, web-ide, sap-web-ide

I want to extend and run 'RT_COUNT_STOCK' (Count Stock) application in SAP WEBIDE. But since the application is using a reusable library which is deployed as 'RTST_REUSE', the application is failing to run in WEBIDE.

I get the following error:

[image]

I have imported 'RTST_REUSE' application as well in my workspace, but still the 'RT_COUNT_STOCK' app does not run.

Please help.

Thanks and Regards,

Vinuta

Comment: Could you please post your index.html, component.js and neo-app.json ?
Have you checked in SICF, that your services are activated ?
Please see also [Getting an error while running a Fiori app - 'Could not open app. Try again later'.](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3845636)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your run configuration and bind the application resources to your local worksapce:

- Right click on your project root then select "Run" > "Run Configurations ..."
- Select your run configuration and then go under "Advanced Settings"
- Under Application Resources check the checkbox for "Use my workspace first".
- "Save and Run"